# Replacing values when mapping through an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am mapping out an array in one of my React components.

Is it possible to replace values when using map to write out each member of an array?

For example, if I have this array:

```
{ rowInfo.value.map(
      weaponIds => (<span>{weaponIds}</span>)
) }
```

that writes out:

```
<span> 1 </span>
<span> 3 </span>
<span> 4 </span>
<span> 8 </span>
```

Can I change it so that, instead of printing out the Id, it prints out the name of the weapon associated with that ID?

so :

```
<span> Pistol </span>
<span> Hunting Rifle </span>
<span> Machete </span>
<span> Machine Gun </span>
```

Note that the names do not exist in the API.

So I would somehow have to assign it so that 1 = Pistol, 2 = Dagger, 3 = Hunting Rifle, etc...

I tried writing out like this:

```
{ rowInfo.value.map(
      weaponIds => (<span>{weaponIds => (1 = Pistol), (2 = Dagger) etc... }</span>)
) }
```

But that throws a bunch of errors and my page no longer loads at all.

Thanks for any helps! :)

Comment: You could make an object and look the values up in them, `weaponIds => ({1: 'Pistol', 2: 'Dagger', ...}[weaponIds])` or something of that nature

Comment: Why don't you make an object like ```const weapons = {1: 'Pistol', 2: 'Dagger'};``` and use this as ```weapons[weaponIds]```

Answer (score 2):

Create an object with all keys and value

```
const obj = {
  1: 'Pistol',
  2: 'Dagger',
  //...
}
```

Then, use:

```
{ 
  rowInfo.value.map(
    weaponIds => (<span>{obj[weaponIds]}</span>) 
  ) 
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks but would this make it so whenever it finds a 1, it prints out 'Pistol', or a 2, it prints out 'Dagger' instead of printing out 1 and 2?  Thx

Comment: obj[1] will return "Pistol" or any other value which corresponds to key - 1

Comment: will this work in javascript for React? Or do I need something else?

Comment: When I try this, is says 'Pistol' is not defined or 'Dagger' is not defined.  Do I need to create something new for each?  Thanks

Comment: just updated, it should be const obj = {
  1: 'Pistol',
  2: 'Dagger'
}
'Pistol' or 'Dagger' is string

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an Enum?

```
enum Weapons {
   Pistol = 1,
   Dagger,
   'Machine Gun',
   ...
}

{ rowInfo.value.map(
  weaponIds => (<span>{Weapons[weaponIds]}</span>)
) }
```

Comment: Hi noo I haven't, I'm not sure how this would work in React?  thanks

Comment: I just saw you are using javascript, not typescript. javascript doesnt support enums out of the box, sorry :(.

Comment: oh ok Im sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: actually you did in the tags